# Separate characters from digits with or without fractional part

Tags: python, regex

I am still learning REGEX, and I've run into an issue ...

I am trying to separate a string that is composed of a mixture of letters and numbers that are in decimal format:

AB0.500CD1.05EF2.29

Into something like this:

list1 = AB,CD,EF

list2 = 0.500,1.05,2.29

A complication to all this is that I also have strings that look like this:

AB1CD2EF3

Which I'd also like to separate into this:

list1 = AB,CD,EF

list2 = 1,2,3

A previous inquiry yielded the following snippet,

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)')
for (letters, numbers) in re.findall(pattern,cmpnd):
    print numbers
    print letters
```

This example works fine for strings of the 2nd kind, but only "finds" the leading digit in the numbers that contain decimal places in the strings of the first kind.

I've attempted an approach using the following line:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+(\.[0-9]))')
```

But this results in an error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Thanks for any and all assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a dot to the character class containing the digits:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9.]+)')
```

Comment: This actually works well. It splits the strings into letter groups and numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

is generated because you added a new matching group to the regular expression

```
([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+(\.[0-9]))
                --^^^^^^^^^--
```

leading to an inconsistency between the number of assignments (i.e. 2 assignments) in

```
for (letters, numbers) in re.findall(pattern,cmpnd):
  --^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--
```

and the number of matches (i.e. 3 matches) returned by the regular expression in each group

```
for (letters, numbers) in re.findall(pattern,cmpnd):
                        --^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--
```

You could easily fix these by updating the unpacking

```
for (letters, numbers, _) in re.findall(pattern, cmpnd):
```

But you still have a problem. Your regular expression won't accept number without decimal part. You could extend the regular expression doing the matching group for the decimal part optional:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+(\.[0-9])?)
                         --^--
```

The code would look like this at this point:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+(\.[0-9])?)')
for (letters, numbers, _) in re.findall(pattern, text):
  print letters, numbers
```

### Improvements

The third matching group is not being used since it is contained in another bigger one. So, you could make this group a non-matching one, `(?:\.[0-9])?)`.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9])?)')
for (letters, numbers) in re.findall(pattern, text):
  print letters, numbers
```

Also, if you don't want a compulsory validation of the number format you can simplify it. That is, accepting a string composed by consecutive digits and periods in any order as a number, `[0-9.]+`.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9.]+)')
for (letters, numbers, _) in re.findall(pattern, text):
  print letters, numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern,

```
[A-Z]{2}(\d+(\.(\d)+)?)
```

or

```
[A-Z]+(\d+(\.(\d)+)?)
```

Comment: or maybe `[A-Z]+|(\d+(\.(\d)+)?)`